# how to apply rto_min to a certain host in centos?

Tags: networking, centos

I want to apply the rto_min of 3 sec or 6 sec to any route from my server to an ip for example 192.168.18.45. How can I do that in centos?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change rto_min for a route with

```
ip route change [route] dev eth0 rto_min 3s
```

If you have tried that and you get strange results when you run the command (for example)

```
ip route change  192.168.254.0/24 dev eth0 rto_min 400ms
```

and are getting strange results

```
ip route show 192.168.254.0/24 dev eth0
192.168.254.0/24  scope link  rto_min lock 0.57ms
```

There is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=838482) in the output formatting of the command.